# Difference between Top and Limit Keyword in SQL

Tags: sql

A quick Question. Suppose I have the following two queries:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Persons;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Persons limit 2;
```

I want to know the difference between the execution of the above 2 queries?
Basically, I want to know when should I use the `limit` keyword and when it is appropriate to use the `top` keyword. 
Also, How does the database return results based on the above 2 queries.

Comment: AFAIK there is no real difference. TOP is SQL Server syntax and limit is MySQL syntax. Different DBMS but the same purpose.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you are using **SQL Server** use `TOP`.
if you are using **MySQL** or **PostgreSQL** use `LIMIT`!

AFAIK there is no product that currently supports both. [Here's one](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit-simple) list of current implementations and [here's another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Result_limits) (covers more products but in less detail)

Comment: SAP HANA [supports TOP as well as LIMIT](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/fcf24075191014a89e9dc7b8408b26/content.htm?frameset=/en/20/fc06a7751910149892c0d09be21a38/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/plain.htm&node_id=195).

Comment: So does AWS Redshift. 
select top 10 * from ...; 
select * from ... limit 100

Comment: Snowflake supports both

Comment: Most, if not all, of the above didn't exist in 2011

Answer (score 47):

As stated in my comment for Martin Smith's answer above, there are products that support both, `LIMIT` and `TOP` (as you can see [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/fcf24075191014a89e9dc7b8408b26/content.htm?frameset=/en/20/fc06a7751910149892c0d09be21a38/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/plain.htm&node_id=195)). The difference is that `TOP` only selects the first n records, but `LIMIT` allows the definition of an offset to retrieve a specific range of records:

```
SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

This statement selects the 5 records, after skipping 10 records and this isn't possible with `TOP`.

The example I posted is only checked against the DBS I linked above. I didn't check a SQL standard, because of a lack of time.

Comment: "This statement selects the first 5 records, after skipping 10 records and this isn't possible with TOP." - is there any way you can use top in the same manner

Comment: @RalphDingus with nested TOP if you are on a product/version that does not support OFFSET ... FETCH or similar

Answer (score 15):

TOP & LIMIT both work on amazon Redshift

Comment: Indeed they do: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_with_TOP.html

Answer (score 13):

`limit` works on MySQL and PostgreSQL, `top` works on SQL Server, `rownum` works on Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference. The `TOP` and `LIMIT` keywords function identically, and will return the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The `DISTINCT` command and the `TOP` command can't work together.

The `DISTINCT` command and the `LIMIT` command do work together.

So if you are using `DISTINCT` you must use `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between top and limit is, top only work with single table where as limit can work with join as well

Answer (score -8):

one big mistake, LIMIT is slowly because select is return full and then database server return only limited data. When it is posible used to TOP.

Comment: this certainly isn't true in postgresql - which doesn't support the TOP syntax anyway -- do a SELECT with a LIMIT and as long as there is no ORDER BY clause you will get an exit as soon as the query can logically finish with that limit.