# How to select 5 rows with greatest values from db with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have database with items and prices.
I have to select 5 rows with greatest price tag. Like this - 1. greatest, 2. greatest, 3. greatest etc.

Can anyone help me with query?

Comment: Please show some previews of your database structure.

Comment: Does the rank number need to be in the query results, or can you process in the application logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure without your database structure, but something like this;

```
SELECT TOP (5) item, MAX(price) AS [Price]
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

As outlined by Dave Chen below, this (`TOP`) is the SQL Server syntax, for MySQL/Postgres use `LIMIT`, for Oracle, `ROWNUM`.

Comment: regardless of knowing the variables at hand, your answer is correct +1

Comment: I suggest the OP read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668540/difference-between-top-and-limit-keyword-in-sql