# SQL: How to find if there is at least one record matching a condition

Tags: sql, optimization, count

In one of my database tables, I want to know if there is atleast one record corresponding to a condition.

The query i wrote is 
Count(*) from table where (condition)
And in my program, i can check whether the result is a non-zero value.
It works fine.

How can we optimize this? I dont want to wait till it finds the total count of records matching the condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 AS found
FROM tablename
WHERE ...
```

Then check if the query returns a single row or not.

In this case engine will immediately return you result as soon as it finds the first row (assuming you don't add `ORDER BY`)

Comment: This solution was useful indeed.. 
Still have another qn.. 
Select column from table where condition LIMIT 1 
is another aproach i successfully tried. 
Can you comment which one would be optmal?

Comment: @Dhanesh: I'm confused now what DBMS you're talking about. Is it sql server? mysql?

Comment: @Dhanesh: then the answer - there is no difference. If sqlite optimizes that (I don't know how its optimizer works actually) - then use whatever you like more.

Comment: TOP and LIMIT are specific to DBMS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5668540/6068036

Answer (score 10):

SQL has `exists` which can be used for this. This will return 1 if the query returns a result, and 0 otherwise.

```
Select Case When Exists (<query>) Then 1 Else 0 End as X
```

Answer (score -4):

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM InsertProductTb", con);

```
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

         }
```

Comment: What will happen if it matches a million of rows?

Comment: you must to determine a specific  condition

Comment: so how different your answer from the ideas of OP in the question?

Comment: sorry I though he know ho to make his condition but he don't know how to check if there is a record in database or not

Comment: Have you actually read the question completely? The only phrase that ends with question mark is "How can we optimize this?". How do you think, does it look like "he don't know how to check if there is a record"?

Comment: you can answer the question without talk ??!!
he will choose the right answer :)

Comment: My qn was to get an optimized query. Sorry that i mislead Omar. Thanks for ur support zerkms :), and thanks for the effort Omar