# How to restrict SQL query from returning more than one item with a certain ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL DB I have items table and a few other tables related to the items, for example item_category, item_photos and so on.

Im doing this query to get some info from several tables, and I need a certain item_id to be returned only once.

The problem is, one of the items has two records in the item_photos table:

```
item_id  item_image

83       image.jpg

83       image2.jpg
```

I only need one of those returned, no matter which one

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user_items
       LEFT JOIN items ON (items.item_id = user_items.item_id) 
       INNER JOIN item_categories ON (item_categories.item_id = items.item_id)
       INNER JOIN item_subcategories ON (item_subcategories.item_id = items.item_id)
       INNER JOIN brands ON (brands.brand_id = items.item_brand)
       INNER JOIN item_photos ON (item_photos.item_id = items.item_id)
       INNER JOIN place_items ON (place_items.item_id = items.item_id)
       INNER JOIN places ON (places.place_id = place_items.place_id)
 WHERE user_items.user_id = :user_id;
```

Comment: Which one do you want? Also subcategories appear to have no relation to categories. This is odd, don't you think?

Comment: I need any one of them, doesnt matter. What do you mean with that subcategory thing?

Comment: Well, typically, a thing belongs to a subcategory, and a subcategory belongs to a category. You've got something different going on, which is cool.

Comment: I still dont understand. the product has category 1 (automotive) and subcategory 78 (spare parts) which has parent_category_id = 1.

Comment: If subcategory 78 belongs to parent_category 1, then the relationship between `item` and one of those two tables is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL allows you to cheat: add `GROUP BY item_id`

In strict SQL, this is an error, an invalid use of a GROUP BY, but in MySQL it is allowed, and simply returns an arbitrary row with each ID.

Comment: And probably best avoided for exactly that reason

Comment: @Strawberry True. But if it doesn't matter exactly which one you get, there's no real issue.

Comment: so I put GROUP BY item_id after the WHERE statement?

Comment: Perhaps, but in my (limited) experience, that's often symptomatic of bigger problems with the design.

Comment: so what do I do instead

Comment: @J.Kowalski First, you decide which one you want! And then you look at anything tagged [groupwise-max] [mysql] :-)

Comment: You need to ask yourself why there are two items with the same ID in the first place ^_^

Comment: Strawberry - I need one of the images for that item, no matter which one. Niet, I dont have two items with the same ID, I have one item that has two images.

Comment: If it doesn't matter which one, then `GROUP BY` will work okay.

Comment: Using the TOP or the LIMIT function would be a better alternative. Abusing a function like group by to achieve something a normal function can do is generally a bad Idea. just Imagine this is behaviour was a MYSQL bug which is fixed in the next version - you upgrade the Server and your Application does not work anymore...

Comment: @BigM But my understanding here is that there are multiple `item_id`s in the result set, OP just wants distinct item IDs.

Comment: then you should get them with a limited subselect on item_photos where the duplicate come from. that may be more difficult than your solution, but using a bug to your vavour is never going to be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

As you said that it doesn't matter which one you get you can just collect them via a limited Subselect. 
TSQL Expression would be Top 1

```
SELECT Top 1 * 
FROM item_photos 
where user_id = :user_id
```

MySQL uses the word LIMIT

```
SELECT * 
FROM item_photos 
where user_id = :user_id 
Limit 1
```

have this link for more Info: 
[Difference between Top and Limit Keyword in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668540/difference-between-top-and-limit-keyword-in-sql)

I'll leave it to you figuring out how to insert this into your SQL

I think this is a better Solution than abusing the Group by Function as this could be a bug that will be fixed sometime