# How to get First Highest or Second Highest or Third Highest Salary from Employee table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am sharing my SQL if someone has better than this please post here.

To get First Highest Salary Run below query:

```
select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1;
```

To get Second Highest Salary Run below query:

```
select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1,1;
```

To get Third Highest Salary Run below query:

```
select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 2,1;
```

Comment: That looks like the best way to do it. What's the problem?

Comment: Is this mysql question?

Comment: My question is what about If same salary exist then?

Comment: I prefer e.g. for the third: '...limit 1 offset 2' for readability.

Comment: you welcome robsn...its most commonly used syntax which i have posted here but for readability i agree with your answer.

Comment: @Lavkush As Sadikhasan says... If for example the highest salary exists 10 times then it completely screws over your sql... you need to do some grouping!

Comment: @PaulZahra : I have updated my answer (being more specific: getting the highest salary information only)

Comment: @Lavkush then see my answer below and use either a group by or distinct

Comment: Hi All,I got the Final Answer:

To get First Highest Salary Run below query:

`select salary from employee group by salary order by salary desc limit 1`;

To get Second Highest Salary Run below query:

`select salary from employee group by salary order by salary desc limit 1,1`;
OR

`select salary from employee group by salary order by salary desc
limit 1 offset 1`;

To get Third Highest Salary Run below query:
`select salary from employee group by salary order by salary desc limit 2,1`;
OR

`select salary from employee group by salary order by salary desc
limit 1 offset 2`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine... apart from if multiples of salaries exist... i.e. if the top 10 salaries are 1000 then the top salary = 1000, the top 3rd one = 1000 etc etc

Use group by...

```
select salary
from employee
GROUP BY salary
order by salary desc limit 1;
```

or a distinct...

```
select DISTINCT(salary)
from employee
order by salary desc limit 1;
```

Comment: thanks @Paul Zahra.....i got your point.

Answer (score 4):

You can get Top Nth salary using this query where `N` is Nth highest salary.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N) = (
               SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
               FROM Employee Emp2
               WHERE Emp2.Salary >= Emp1.Salary
               )
```

Comment: i think its an alternate way but not a better one.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM employee ORDER BY salary desc
```

To get the second highest one

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC OFFSET 1
```

And the get the third one

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC OFFSET 2
```

But if you are going to use all three in the same piece of code i would suggest to get them all 3 at the same time since this sashes you the execution of 2 queues. i would like to suggest the folioing query to get the top 3 highest salaries

```
SELECT TOP 3 FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC
```

Comment: Umm... this is a [tag:mysql] question

Comment: your answer i OK with SQL but i posted it for MySQL...by the way NO Issue,its great learning...

Comment: You have both tags, mysql and sql

Comment: As far as i know this would work on mysql, with part does not work for mysql (i am a mssql user)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use query like this one

```
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Than when you parse it you can go throuht each row. I think it si better to use `LIMIT 3` than `TOP 3`. Referrence [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668540/difference-between-top-and-limit-keyword-in-sql)