# IF row exists THEN delete row in mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, exists

I have a query like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = ? LIMIT 1) THEN
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE col2 = ?
END IF
```

But I don't know why above query does not work. Also this does not work too:

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = ? LIMIT 1) BEGIN
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE col2 = ?
END
```

MySQL tell my there is a syntax error, How can I fix it?

Comment: MySQL is (generally) not a procedural programming language; you can't use `IF` statements outside of a procedure. The documentation does state this. If you were to actually _read_ it, you may also find the answer to your question. Is there some reason you were unable to read the documentation?

Comment: Yeah. So you're pretty much stuck with doing the `IF` in your application logic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit actually I saw [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639854/check-if-a-row-exists-otherwise-insert#639874) and thought maybe it is possible to using `IF` in mysql! anyway ok thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can move the condition into the `WHERE` clause of `DELETE` to achieve the same effect, like this:

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE col2 = ?
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = ? LIMIT 1)
```

Note that the two `?`s have switched places with relation to the original query.

Comment: @Sajad As far as I know, only `limit 1` works with MySql. `TOP 1` is Sql Server syntax ([related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5668540/335858)).

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` is unnecessary; `EXISTS` sort of does that.