# Select Top # in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

Does Presto SQL really lack TOP X functionality in SELECT statements?

If so, is there a workaround in the meantime?

https://prestodb.io/

Comment: Do you mean ORDER BY with LIMIT?

Comment: This is actually two different things.

Comment: Most of the time, TOP N functions the same as ORDER BY with LIMIT, but I am working within an edge case where it doesn't. Oh well. :/

Comment: Can you describe what the TOP X function does, or what you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I recommend you take the time to test the difference between TOP and LIMIT instead.  This link is a good starting point, but testing the two will provide more analysis. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668540/difference-between-top-and-limit-keyword-in-sql

Comment: According to that post and all linked documentation in that post, TOP and LIMIT are the same.  What specifically were you attempting to do?

Comment: @DainSundstrom something like `select mode() within group (order by X) from abc` probably? That's valid Postgres and it's simplifying life a lot when dealing with nested sub-sub-sub-queries, compared to the solution posted as accepted answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you simply want to limit the number of rows in the result set, you can use `LIMIT`, with or without `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT department, salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If you want the top values per group, you can use the standard SQL `row_number()` window function. For example, to get the top 3 employees per department by salary:

```
SELECT department, salary
FROM (
  SELECT department, salary, row_number() OVER (
    PARTITION BY department
    ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rn
  FROM employees
)
WHERE rn <= 3
```

Comment: For everyone else, this is as close as we get in Presto.Yeah, this is what I wound up doing.  Using TOP N makes it the query both faster and easier to read.  I was dealing with large volume of data and trying to avoid memory limits.

Ran the code multiple times for subsets of the data and then aggregated it back together.

Thank you!

Comment: Ew.  It ate my pretty pretty formatting.  Haha!  Thanks again, David!

Comment: Thanks so much, helped me a bunch! 
It took me a bit to realize there was a missing comma between 'salary' and 'row_number()' in the third line of that second example.