# Select the actor with the most movies played

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.
1) dbo.movies

```
+------------+-------------+------------+
| movie_id   | movie_name  | actor_id   | 
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1          | name1       |     1      | 
| 2          | name2       |     1      | 
| 3          | name3       |     4      | 
| 4          | name4       |     2      |
| 5          | name5       |     1      |
| 6          | name6       |     5      |
| 7          | name7       |     3      |
+------------+-------------+------------+
```

2) dbo.actors

```
+------------+-------------+
| actor_id   | actor_name  | 
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | name1       | 
| 2          | name2       |
| 3          | name3       |
| 4          | name4       |
| 5          | name5       |
+------------+-------------+
```

I want to `SELECT` the `actor_id` and `actor_name` that played in the most movies.

Although I know how to find the most movies an actor has played, I can't find who that actor is:

```
select max(y.x)
from (select count(actor_id) as x from movies group by actor_id) y
```

Comment: aside: Your table structure is a bit weird - it implies every movie can only have 1 actor. You probably want a junction table between movie and actor (Many-to-many relationship)

Comment: Yeah I know, just imagine that each movie goes to 1 actor and 1 actor can go to a lot of movies for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the `actors` table to get the name, order by the count and take only the first record

```
select top 1 a.actor_name, count(*) as cnt
from actors a
join movies m on a.actor_id = m.actor_id
group by a.actor_id, a.actor_name
order by count(*) desc
```

What if 2 actors acted in the same number of movies, and I want to get them both?

One method would be

```
select a.actor_name, count(*) as cnt
from actors a
join movies m on a.actor_id = m.actor_id
group by a.actor_id, a.actor_name
having count(*) = (select top 1 count(*) max_cnt from movies group by actor_id order by count(*) desc)
```

Comment: What if I have 2 actors that have the same nomber of movies on first place, and want to get them both?

Comment: I get this errors on the second way:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Comment: I think that should be `count(m.*)` not `m.count(*)`

Comment: Now I'm getting this: Msg 1015, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Addition to the `TOP` syntax. `limit` works on MySQL and PostgreSQL, `top` works on SQL Server, `rownum` works on Oracle. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668540/difference-between-top-and-limit-keyword-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

**Query**

Give a rank based on the count of movies acted and then join it with actors table.

```
;with cte as (
    select num = dense_rank() over(
        order by count(actor_id) desc
    ), actor_id,  count(actor_id) as [count]
    from movies
    group by actor_id
)
select * from actors t1
where exists(
    select 1 from cte t2
    where t1.actor_id = t2.actor_id
    and t2.num = 1
);
```

or last part can be like below.

```
select t1.actor_id, t1.actor_name
from #actors t1
join cte t2
on t1.actor_id = t2.actor_id
where t2.num = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check This.

using MAX :

```
        select movie_name, max(TotalMovies) from 
        (

        select distinct a.movie_name,count(m.actor_id) as TotalMovies
        from movies m inner join actors a on a.actor_id   = m.actor_id
        group by movie_name  

        )a
        group by movie_name
```

display All Actors with TotalMovies

```
        select distinct a.movie_name,count(m.actor_id) as TotalMovies
        from movies m inner join actors a on a.actor_id   = m.actor_id
        group by movie_name  
        order by TotalMovies desc
```

Using TOP 1 :

```
        select distinct top 1 a.movie_name,count(m.actor_id) as TotalMovies
        from movies m inner join actors a on a.actor_id   = m.actor_id
        group by movie_name
        order by TotalMovies desc
```

Comment: I get this error on the second dinstinct:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Comment: I get this error when using MAX:
Ambiguous column name 'name'.

Comment: When you say name, in what property are you refering to?

Comment: try to check with your column names. i just used name instead of movies_name. it means I created temp table for my use. and i a giving name to 'names' instead of 'movies_names'

Answer (score 1):

Put another select

```
select * from  dbo.actors where actor_id = (select max(y.x)
from (select count(actor_id) as x from movies group by actor_id) y)
```

Comment: Won't work: nested query `SELECT MAX<x.y>••` doesn't return an actor ID

Answer (score 1):

Just select the `actor_id` from the sub query, arrange into descending order and select the top record.

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(actor_id) AS x,actor_id AS z FROM 
               movies GROUP BY actor_id ORDER BY COUNT(actor_id) DESC
```

For the 2nd Question

```
SELECT *,(SELECT actor_name FROM actors WHERE actor_id=Z.actor_id) AS Name FROM 
        (SELECT COUNT(actor_id) AS X,actor_id FROM movies GROUP BY actor_id) AS Z
WHERE X=(SELECT MAX(Y) FROM 
        (SELECT COUNT(actor_id) AS Y FROM 
            movies GROUP BY actor_id))
```

Comment: I get the following errors:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Now this: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: It works, but what if I have 2 actors that have the same number of movies on first place, and want to get them both?

Comment: I get this now:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Edited the answer. Try it.

Comment: It gets this error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
and highlights the last line

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(actor.actor_id),actor.actor_name FROM movies join actor on actor.actor_id=movies.actor_id group by  actor.actor_id,actor.actor_name having count(movies.actor_id) =(
SELECT MAX(counted) FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(actor_id) AS counted
    FROM movies
    GROUP BY actor_id
) AS counts
)
```

Comment: @user2975038 it is working fine in mysql. anyways try now.

Comment: now i get this:
Column 'actor.actor_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user2975038 added it in group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as full_name, count(f.actor_id) as num_movies
from actor a
inner join film_actor f
using (actor_id)
group by f.actor_id,1
order by count(f.actor_id) desc
limit 3;
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements all other answers.