# Why won't RANK and DENSE_RANK functions work?

Tags: mysql

In trying to use Sequel Pro and MySQL Workbench, I cannot get RANK or DENSE_RANK to work.

Here's a generic query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY `Ticket Sales`) , 
School
FROM schools;
```

Sequel Pro returns this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY `Ticket Sales`) , 
>   School
>   FROM schools' at line 2

MySQL Workbench returns this error:

> Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION RANK does not exist.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: That error message is not joking.

Comment: Check the function in MySQL, I don't think you'll find that function. The error message is pretty clear....

Comment: it's SQL function : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql

Comment: Hey there. Based on your comment on the answer, it occurred to me that my previous comment probably came across as less good-natured than it was intended to be. From my experience with learning MySQL after working with SQL Server for a while, I can warn you about another difference that you'll probably encounter at some point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668540/difference-between-top-and-limit-keyword-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-dense-rank-function-mysql-sql-query.html.

It explains that there is no DENSE_RANK function in MySQL and offers an alternative approach.

Comment: Bingo, thanks. Didn't realize that it wasn't also a MySQL function. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris how could you not realise this when the error message told you so? "FUNCTION RANK **does not exist**"

Comment: I'm a novice and still learning. It had literally never occurred to me until 10 minutes ago that there were multiple versions SQL with different commands. Thanks for being so helpful and encouraging.